# How do I install bsddb3?

Tags: python

How do I install bsddb3? This is on 3.7 and that's what happened:

```
    C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\hashcat>pip install bsddb3
Collecting bsddb3
  Using cached bsddb3-6.2.9.tar.gz (230 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1nu7l6zy\\bsddb3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1nu7l6zy\\bsddb3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-hq87gwaj'
         cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1nu7l6zy\bsddb3\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1nu7l6zy\bsddb3\setup.py", line 42, in <module>
        import setup3
      File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1nu7l6zy\bsddb3\setup3.py", line 385, in <module>
        with open(os.path.join(incdir, 'db.h'), 'r') as f :
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db/include\\db.h'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: try updating ```setuptools```

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/bsddb3/), bsddb3 is compatible with Python 3 up to 3.6. They also suggest you to use [berkeleydb](https://pypi.org/project/berkeleydb/) with newer versions of Python.

If you really want to use bsddb3, a solution would be installing the Python 3.6 in your computer, as you can have multiples versions installed.